# Is there a way to insert color formatting in one element of a string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

Suppose I have this output from a string array displayed here:

> ProductID was = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
>   17, 18, ,

And I want to mark the 15th element (that's number 16 above) in red color, leaving the rest black.  The lone red number is based on the value of `ProductId`.

This is my code:

```
string[] indices = new string[20];                                     
string[] indices2 = new string[20];                                    

for (int i = 0; i < allProducts.Count; i++)                            
{                                                                      
    indices[i] = Convert.ToString(allProducts[i].ProductId); //this holds the values shown above          
    indices2[i] = Convert.ToString(allProducts[i].CategoryId);         
}                                                                      

lbl_Indices.Text = "ProductID was = " + string.Join(", ", indices); //this is the output.   
lbl_Indices2.Text = "CategoryID was = " + string.Join(", ", indices2);
```

How can I achieve the desired result ?  Or must I use `RichTextBox` instead? (No need to work out the code, I'll do that--just show me the most appropriate method.  Thanks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RichTextBox` is not exist on web pages, this is for the desktop applications.

In a web page, you use html and in your case you need to warp the number with an html code that make it red. Here is a simple example, wrap it with

```
<span style="color:red;">16</span>
```

Comment: Well, the number 16 can't be hardcoded because the ProductId number will change with every iteration,  I was hoping for a C# code implementation for formatting the element that contains the value of ProductId in each iteration.

Comment: @MichaelD.O'Connor Its really very easy to do it your self, and to hard to do it my self because I do not know how is your code at your program... and if you really can not do that, I am worry what actually do you know about programming... maybe is some one else job to do it ?

Comment: As far as "wrapping the number with an html code", not much.  I do know HTML and other languages.  Do you mean something like this in C#?: `var span = "<span style=\"color: rgb(102, 204, 255); font-size: 11pt;\">"; `  Because I cannot use your code in the mark up.  Only in C#.

Comment: @MichaelD.O'Connor Yes you need c# to format the output, just like you all ready do on your code on the question.